# Insert USP output to table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which is pulling data based on parameter criteria and store it into a table.

When I am running it the first time, the query executes successfully, but when running for a second time, it's throwing an error as `MY_NEW_TABLE` already exists.

Now the problem is I want to retain data for each year and week.

What change do I have to do so I can pass the value for parameter and output saved to the table?

Code

```
CREATE PROC usp_myproc 
    @year, @week
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COL1, COL2 
    INTO MY_NEW_TABLE
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE YEAR = @YEAR AND WEEK = @WEEK
END

EXEC usp_myproc @year = 2018, @week = 01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest you are probably best creating the table once, and then changing your stored procedure so that it will only ever `INSERT INTO` new records?

However, to answer your question, if you did something like this then it should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_myproc (
    @YEAR INT,
    @WEEK INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('MY_NEW_TABLE') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MY_NEW_TABLE
        SELECT COL1, COL2 
        FROM [TABLE]
        WHERE [YEAR] = @YEAR AND [WEEK] = @WEEK;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT COL1, COL2 
        INTO MY_NEW_TABLE
        FROM [TABLE]
        WHERE [YEAR] = @YEAR AND [WEEK] = @WEEK;
    END;
END;

EXEC usp_myproc @YEAR = 2018, @WEEK = 01;
```